Editing response body in org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter implementation
I use Reactive stack and I need to change the response body when I get an error status code.
There is my method below:
 @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {

    return chain.filter(exchange).then(Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
          var response = exchange.getResponse();
          var statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
          var serverError = getError(statusCode);

          if (serverError != null) {
            serverError.setErrorCode("000");
            serverError.setSource("ms-mobile-agw");
            String message;
            try {
              message = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(serverError);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
              throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            byte[] bytes = message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            var dataBufferFactory = new NettyDataBufferFactory(ByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT);
            var buffer = (NettyDataBuffer) dataBufferFactory.wrap(bytes);
            response.writeWith(Mono.just(buffer));
          }
        }
    ));
  }

It doesn't work. Response isn't changed. Where is my mistake?
